# Controls inside a WPF Popup Control are offset

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

First of all, this is my second day designing Forms using WPF. At first, I have found that it is easier to manage the controls.

I am trying to put some controls inside a `WPF` `Popup` and it is behaving differently than I expected. 
What seems to be the issue?

```
<Popup Placement="Center" Height="38" Width="153">
     <StackPanel>
          <TextBlock Background="LightBlue"> This is popup text</TextBlock>
          <Button Content="This is button on a Popup" />
     </StackPanel>
</Popup>
```

The popup is placed inside a Grid and seems to be centered. But the stackpanel and the controls inside it  are placed as in this picture.

[image]

I get this behaviour only with the Popup control.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I would first suggest you to read about what is popup in wpf from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/popup-overview#what-is-a-popup.

The intent of the popup you have writtened here can be to just open a popup when you over your mouse on the grid or when you click mouse on the grid.
pop up control can not be showed on your design, insted you can visualize it as how a pop up message box comes on a window.
The controls you have writtened inside of your popup will be appear when your popup is opened.

If you want your popup control to aligned properly, first align your 
it with the grid and then set your stack panel orientation and alignment propery to have a better look.